# Create User in Unix that can login via SSH

Tags: unix, ssh

I created a User ("myuser") with a Password ("mypw") on a Unix server, whom I granted acces only to certain files.
I try to login to the server with ssh: `$ ssh myuser@myserver.com`  and then I enter the password "mypw". Still, I am not granted access: `"Permission denied, please try again."`

Is there something I forgot / something additional I have to do with the user in order to give him access via ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit simple, but try sudo it?
Or Sudo su before running the command?

Comment: I created the user as admin, so that would not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manipulate keys at any point ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHoRYCY-LYU